# How to delete/undeploy an ear-file from weblogic via maven (if existent) or update the ear-file?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have a weblogic server (12.2.1.3.0) and want to deploy an ear-file via maven. That works fine. But when I want to re-deploy it an error is thrown. The reason is that the context-root is the same. So I have to undeploy the ear-file first and then re-deploy it or update the ear-file. The question is - how to do that.
I ran maven via eclipse with "clean install".

pom of the parent project:

```
<modules>
    <module>Aras-ear</module>
    <module>Aras-web</module>
    <module>Aras-ejb</module>
</modules>

<profiles>
    <!-- Profil für ARAS (normal) -->
    <profile>
        <id>aras</id>
        <properties>
            <datasource.name>ArasDataSource</datasource.name>
            <environment.name>ARAS</environment.name>
            <rootcontext.name>aras</rootcontext.name>
            <earfile.name>Aras-ear</earfile.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- Profil für ARAS (Nightly Build) -->
    <profile>
        <id>aras_nb</id>
        <properties>
            <datasource.name>ArasNbDataSource</datasource.name>
            <environment.name>ARAS-NB</environment.name>
            <rootcontext.name>aras_nb</rootcontext.name>
            <earfile.name>Aras_nb-ear</earfile.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <!-- Lässt das Setzen der Variablen in den Resources zu -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

pom of the ear-project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>xxx.yyy</groupId>
    <artifactId>Aras</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Aras-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                 <!-- finalName ist z.B. "aras-ear-1.0" oder "aras_nb-ear-1.0" (gibt Namen des ear-Files an) -->
                <finalName>${earfile.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                <modules> 
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>Aras-web</artifactId>
                        <!-- rootcontext.name = "aras" oder "aras_nb" (gibt Aufruf-URL vor) -->
                        <contextRoot>/${rootcontext.name}</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1-3-0</version>
            <configuration>
                <adminurl>t3://localhost:7001</adminurl>
                <user>weblogic</user>
                <password>welcome1</password>
                <upload>true</upload>
                <action>deploy</action>
                <remote>false</remote>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <!-- source ist entsprechendes Ear-File (je nach gewähltem Profil) im Target-Verzeichnis des ear-Projektes -->
                <source>${project.build.directory}/${earfile.name}-${project.version}.ear</source>
                <name>${earfile.name}-${project.version}</name>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- Wenn ear-File nicht auf WLS vorhanden, wird execution "clean" Fehler werfen -->
                <!-- <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>undeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution> -->
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried the code

```
<execution>
    <id>clean</id>
    <phase>clean</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>undeploy</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

but that didn't work. The error code was:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:12.2.1-3-0:undeploy (clean) on project Aras-ear: weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149163]The domain edit lock is owned by another session in non-exclusive mode. This deployment operation requires exclusive access to the edit lock and therefore cannot proceed. If using "Automatically Aquire Lock and Activate Changes" in the Administration Console, then the lock will expire shortly, so retry this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try "mvn com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:12.2.1-3-0:clean"